# How does elastic beanstalk starts an app

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Its probably a simple one.

I cannot figure out how does elastic beanstalk knows how to start a nodejs app.

I know for code deploy I can specify commands in appspec file, but for elastic beanstalk I cannot find a place that can run a command

```
node myserver.js
```

for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk will default to using "npm start", so if you want to use that command then you'll need to add the following into the scripts block of your package.json

```
"start": "node myserver.js"
```